# Scala External DSL -- Multi line string literal

Tags: scala, dsl

I am trying to define an external DSL using the scala parser combinators. I see that the 'stringLit' token parser does not accomodate multi line strings using the triple quotes. Is there something similar to a multiLineStringLit in the scala parser combinator world?

Thanks in advance,
Kishore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of, but it's not too hard to write your own:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

object myParser extends JavaTokenParsers {
  def mlStringLiteral: Parser[String] = (
    "\"\"\"" +
    """(\n|[^"\p{Cntrl}\\]|\\[\\/bfnrt]|\\u[a-fA-F0-9]{4})*""" +
    "\"\"\""
  ).r
}
```

This is just [`stringLiteral`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.2/src/library/scala/util/parsing/combinator/JavaTokenParsers.scala#L46) with a couple of minor edits: I've changed the delimiter from `"` to `"""` and added `\n` to the character match.

```
scala> val s = "\"\"\"This is a multi-\nline string literal.\"\"\""
s: java.lang.String = 
"""This is a multi-
line string literal."""

scala> myParser.parseAll(myParser.mlStringLiteral, s)
res0: myParser.ParseResult[String] = 
[2.24] parsed: """This is a multi-
line string literal."""
```

It's not an exact match for Scala's implementation of multi-line string literals (you can't have an unescaped `"` in the string, for example), but it can easily be tweaked, and may work for you as it is.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there any way to achieve the same if  I am using StandardTokenParsers instead of JavaTokenParsers?

Comment: After reading up a little bit more about the differences between StandardTokenParsers and JavaTokenParsers, I ended up going with the latter. I had to modify my code a little bit to strip off the extra quotes with 'StringLiteral' tokenizer.