# Can I use Scala Macros to internalise an external DSL?

Tags: scala, dsl, scala-macros

I would like to implement an external DSL such as SQL in Scala using Macros. I have already seen papers on how to implement [*internal DSLs* with Scala](http://biblion.epfl.ch/EPFL/theses/2011/5007/EPFL_TH5007.pdf). Also, I've recently written an article about [how this can be done in Java](http://blog.jooq.org/2012/01/05/the-java-fluent-api-designer-crash-course/), myself.

Now, internal DSLs always feel a bit clumsy as they have to be implemented and used in the host language (e.g. Scala) and adhere to the host language's syntax constraints. That's why I'm hoping that Scala Macros will allow to internalise an external DSL without any such constraints. However, I don't fully understand Scala Macros and how far I can go with them. I've seen that [SLICK](http://slick.typesafe.com/) and also a much less-known library called [sqltyped](https://github.com/jonifreeman/sqltyped) have started using Macros, but SLICK uses a "Scalaesque" syntax for querying, which isn't really SQL, whereas sqltyped uses Macros to parse SQL strings (which can be done without Macros, too). Also, the various [examples given on the Scala website](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html) are too trivial for what I'm trying to do

#### My question is:

Given an example external DSL defined as some BNF grammar like this:

```
MyGrammar ::= ( 
  'SOME-KEYWORD' 'OPTION'?
    (
      ( 'CHOICE-1' 'ARG-1'+ )
    | ( 'CHOICE-2' 'ARG-2'  )
    )
)
```

Can I implement the above grammar using Scala Macros to allow for client programs like this? Or are Scala Macros not powerful enough to implement such a DSL?

```scala
// This function would take a Scala compile-checked argument and produce an AST
// of some sort, that I can further process
def evaluate(args: MyGrammar): MyGrammarEvaluated = ...

// These expressions produce a valid result, as the argument is valid according
// to my grammar
val result1 = evaluate(SOME-KEYWORD CHOICE-1 ARG-1 ARG-1)
val result2 = evaluate(SOME-KEYWORD CHOICE-2 ARG-2)
val result3 = evaluate(SOME-KEYWORD OPTION CHOICE-1 ARG-1 ARG-1)
val result4 = evaluate(SOME-KEYWORD OPTION CHOICE-2 ARG-2)

// These expressions produce a compilation error, as the argument is invalid
// according to my grammar
val result5 = evaluate(SOME-KEYWORD CHOICE-1)
val result6 = evaluate(SOME-KEYWORD CHOICE-2 ARG-2 ARG-2)
```

Note, I'm not interested in [solutions that parse strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11889081/521799), the way [sqltyped](https://github.com/jonifreeman/sqltyped) does

Comment: Currently macros are limited to vanilla function invocations. That is, the only way to trigger macro expansion is to call a def macro. Moreover arguments to def macros must be well-typed Scala expressions, which means you have to conform to Scala's syntax and typing rules. Future research might lift the latter or also even the former restriction, but how and when it happens is unclear.

Comment: @EugeneBurmako: Thanks for the authoritative feedback! That could qualify as an answer, since you're the Scala Macros guy :-)

Comment: @LukasEder: You say that the string-parsing approach "can be done without Macros", but that's only half true—don't underestimate the value of compile-time safety here.

Comment: @TravisBrown: Yes, I understand that there are benefits in using macros for string parsing. But then, those strings will need to be (inline) string literals, which makes me feel that the string-parsing approach is a "kludge" in between true internal and true external DSLs... Except if I'm missing something?

Comment: No, you're right—as a general DSL solution it's kludgey, but in many cases (particularly where using string literals is already common practice—e.g., regular expressions, SQL queries) being able to validate the embedded language at compile time is a huge plus.

Comment: @TravisBrown: Yes, that's true. Although it only works for static regex/SQL, not dynamic regex/SQL, I guess...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been some time since this question was answered by paradigmatic, but I've just stumbled upon it and thought it's worth extending.

An internalized DSL must indeed be valid Scala code with all the names defined before macro expansion, however one **can** overcome this restriction with a carefully designed syntax and *Dynamics*.

Let's say we wanted to create a simple, silly DSL allowing us to introduce people in a classy way. It might look like this:

```
people {
  introduce John please
  introduce Frank and Lilly please
}
```

We would like to translate (as part of compilation) the above code to an object (of a class derived for example from class `People`) containing definitions of fields of type `Person` for every introduced person - something like this:

```
new People {
    val john: Person = new Person("John")
    val frank: Person = new Person("Frank")
    val lilly: Person = new Person("Lilly")
}
```

To make it possible we need to define some artificial objects and classes having two purposes: defining grammar (somewhat...) and tricking the compiler into accepting undefined names (like `John` or `Lilly`).

```
import scala.language.dynamics

trait AllowedAfterName

object and extends Dynamic with AllowedAfterName {
  def applyDynamic(personName: String)(arg: AllowedAfterName): AllowedAfterName = this
}

object please extends AllowedAfterName

object introduce extends Dynamic {
  def applyDynamic(personName: String)(arg: AllowedAfterName): and.type = and
}
```

These dummy definitions make our DSL code legal - the compiler translates it to the below code before proceeding to macro expansion:

```
people {
    introduce.applyDynamic("John")(please)
    introduce.applyDynamic("Frank")(and).applyDynamic("Lilly")(please)
}
```

Do we need this ugly and seemingly redundant `please`? One could probably come up with a nicer syntax, for example using Scala's postfix operator notation (`language.postfixOps`), but that gets tricky due to semicolon inference (you can try it yourself in the REPL console or IntelliJ's Scala Worksheet). It's easiest to just interlace keywords with undefined names.

As we've made the syntax legal, we can process the block with a macro:

```
def people[A](block: A): People = macro Macros.impl[A]

class Macros(val c: whitebox.Context) {
  import c.universe._

  def impl[A](block: c.Tree) = {
    val introductions = block.children

    def getNames(t: c.Tree): List[String] = t match {
      case q"applyDynamic($name)(and).$rest" =>
        name :: getNames(q"$rest")
      case q"applyDynamic($name)(please)" =>
        List(name)
    }

    val names = introductions flatMap getNames

    val defs = names map { n =>
      val varName = TermName(n.toLowerCase())
      q"val $varName: Person = new Person($n)"
    }

    c.Expr[People](q"new People { ..$defs }")
  }
}
```

The macro finds all the introduced names by pattern matching against the expanded dynamic calls and generates the desired output code. Notice that the macro must be whitebox in order to be allowed to return an expression of a type *derived* from the one declared in the signature.

Comment: That's very interesting! Thanks a lot for following up on this old question... I'll have a closer look later on, but this looks close to what I originally asked for

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. The expression you pass to a macro must be a valid Scala expression and identifiers should be defined.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That's also what Eugene Burmako said in his comment

Comment: Can Lisp macros parse non-lispy syntax?